# SSHFP not working

Tags: ssh, dnssec

I have two machines running OpenBSD v6.9.
Let's be original and call them client and server.

I generated the SSHFP records on the server with :

```
ssh-keygen -r host.domain.tld
```

In the DNS zone, I added the SSHFP record with this line :

```
host      IN      SSHFP 1 2   02323a6fb8a12eba9288930ce2513fc94970e5575996ebede1ee352bd039c531
host      IN      SSHFP 4 2   3eef5929fe85038b2e2a7de70897175e7b0d68328b41ef6466a2fa06f9a8bb49
```

sshd is configured to use only Ed25519 host key but I also keep RSA host key in case on futur need.

The DNS zone is signed with DNSSEC and everything is validated by "https://dnsviz.net/" and "https://dnssec-debugger.verisignlabs.com/".

On the client, there is an Unbound resolver with DNSSEC validator :

```
dig host.domain.tld -t SSHFP

; <<>> dig 9.10.8-P1 <<>> host.domain.tld -t SSHFP
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 9525
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;host.domain.tld.              IN      SSHFP

;; ANSWER SECTION:
host.domain.tld.       3600    IN      SSHFP   4 2 3eef5929fe85038b2e2a7de70897175e7b0d68328b41ef6466a2fa06 f9a8bb49
host.domain.tld.       3600    IN      SSHFP   1 2 02323a6fb8a12eba9288930ce2513fc94970e5575996ebede1ee352b d039c531

;; Query time: 182 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Mon May 17 17:15:46 CEST 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 137
```

It is not mentioned above but if I add +dnssec to the query, the RRSIG SSHFP is displayed.

And the SSH client config file :

```
Host host.domain.tld
    AddressFamily inet
    HostName host.domain.tld
    Port 22
    Protocol 2
    User username
    CheckHostIP yes
    PasswordAuthentication no
    ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
    VerifyHostKeyDNS yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_host.domain.tld
```

But, when I try to connect from the client to the server, it seems that SSHFP does not work :

```
ssh host.domain.tld
The authenticity of host 'host.domain.tld (server_ip_address)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:Pu9ZKf6FA4suKn3nCJcXXnsNaDKLQe9kZqL6Bvmou0k.
Matching host key fingerprint found in DNS.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?
```

According to Internet guides, I should not be asked to accept the key.

So, to summarize :

- SSHFP record generated on the server,
- SSHFP record added to the DNS zone,
- DNS zone signed with DNSSEC,
- client able to query SSHFP records and validate DNSSEC,
- SSH config file with the option "VerifyHostKeyDNS",
- and it is not working.

Here is the detail of the connexion :

```
ssh -v host.domain.tld
OpenSSH_8.6, LibreSSL 3.3.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/username/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/username/.ssh/config line 2: Applying options for host.domain.tld
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to host.domain.tld [server_ip_address] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_ed25519_host.domain.tld type 3
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_ed25519_host.domain.tld-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.6
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.6 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to host.domain.tld:22 as 'username'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/username/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:Pu9ZKf6FA4suKn3nCJcXXnsNaDKLQe9kZqL6Bvmou0k
debug1: found 2 insecure fingerprints in DNS
debug1: matching host key fingerprint found in DNS
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/username/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/username/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: hostkeys file /home/username/.ssh/known_hosts2 does not exist
debug1: hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: hostkeys file /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts does not exist
debug1: hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: hostkeys file /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 does not exist
The authenticity of host 'host.domain.tld (server_ip_address)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:Pu9ZKf6FA4suKn3nCJcXXnsNaDKLQe9kZqL6Bvmou0k.
Matching host key fingerprint found in DNS.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?
```

Do you have any idea of the problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `resolv.conf` look like? Does it have `options edns0`?

Comment: >Håkan Lindqvist
Hello,
Currently, there is no "ends0" option in the resolv.conf.
Let me try this...

Comment: I am not sure that is all there is to your problem, but I'm pretty sure it cannot work without it.

Comment: So, I added "options edns0" to the file resolv.conf and it still does not work :
search localdomain
nameserver 127.0.0.1
options edns0
lookup file bind

Comment: I think this is a bug where OpenBSD is not asking for the resolver to verify DNSSEC, and therefore the DNS response doesn't indicate that it's "secure", and OpenSSH therefore downgrades the VerifyHostKeyDNS from `yes` to `ask`: https://marc.info/?l=openbsd-bugs&m=163717483704678&w=2

Answer (score 6):

OpenSSH v6.9 is very, very, very old.  Latest is OpenSSH v9.0.  I took a look at `dns.c` of the V_6_9 branch of OpenSSH repository.  The key thing to note in your debug output is:

```
found 2 insecure fingerprints in DNS
```

Means that DNSSEC lookup of `host.domain.tld` is not a valid DNS record (totally insecured), despite generally having found two(2) distinct `SSHFP` resource records (secured or not).

This also means that `delv host.domain.tld.` would not put out in the first line the expected message of:

```
$ delv host.domain.tld.
; fully validated
...
```

While the scope of DNSSEC troubleshooting is vast and wide, a solution is not easily had within this post.

I suggest that you plug in your `domain.tld` into one of the two excellent online DNSSEC troubleshooters and go from there:

- https://dnsviz.net/
- https://dnssec-debugger.verisignlabs.com/

Of course, as a last resort, there is [`[dnssec]`](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/dnssec) tag on ServerFault (yet another StackExchange group) and your fav. search engine, but it is quicker to tap an in-house DNSSEC expert for your needs.

## Security Consideration

Of course, you do do have DNSSEC up and running?

Protection of SSHFP is only assured by a properly signed resource record by DNSSEC but, But ... BUT most people (and many ISPs) do not instruct their DNS resolver to only return back a valid DNS record as determined by DNSSEC; having mentioned that, the possibility of SSHFP being hijacked remains.

The problem here is not the confidentiality of the public key (it isn’t confidential).

The problem we have is the integrity of that DNS record holding this public key. While the SSHFP key data is correct in your problem statement, the bug is more of “lack of clarity” yet the logic remains defensively correct.

That is the end for this Original Question post.  But I shall outline even some more security caveats.

## More Caveats

If not distributed securely (via DNSSEC), such SSHFP DNS records can quite easily be tampered with or replaced with another key.  So, DNSSEC must be 'enforced' before even trusting and using `SSHFP`.

If a faked SSH CA server has the wrong public key configured (whose private key is in the hands of someone else), the client ends up by trusting that someone else.

Caution: Improper use of SSHFP records can have serious security consequences; follow these rules to avoid creating security vulnerabilities:

- Do not create SSHFP records in a zone that is not DNSSEC-secured.
- Never configure SSH clients to use SSHFP for a domain that is not DNSSEC-secured.
- Never configure SSH clients to use `VerifyHostKeysDNS yes` unless the current resolver(s) properly validate DNSSEC-approved queries or use a [valid DNSSEC-capable resolver](https://egbert.net/blog/articles/public-nameservers-with-dnssec-support.html) list that I made using a simple `delv domain.tld.` command as a test for its DNSSEC-capability.
- DO ensure that all DNS resolvers directly used by your SSH clients have "accessible DNSSEC"; this means testing your roving laptop at every ISP to get that `; fully validated` check.
- MOST IMPORTANTLY, always, always perform `delv ssh.domain.tld.` and check that first line for `; fully validated` output or make DNSSEC mandatory via `/etc/resolv.conf` (more of this later).

Not following these rules could allow adversaries to create spoofed-SSHFP records for their SSH server(s) to impersonate yours, making SSH connections to the servers insecure and vulnerable to attacks.

You can avoid the "always perform `delv ssh.domain.tld` for `; fully validated`) by having your host's `glibc` library perform this at resolve time (via resolver(3) but NOT the gethostbyname(3) function call).  If you must require absolute DNSSEC-verified DNS queries for all your DNS needs, you could insert the following into your `/etc/resolv.conf` (only if you have glibc v2.38 or later):

File: `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
.
.
.
options edns0
options trust-ad
options ndots:2
.
.
.
search domain.tld
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

Once this gets DNSSEC-secured, there are a couple of steps required to troubleshoot the mechanism of `SSHFP` DNS record and SSH clients.

## Validating SSHFP Setup

The seven(7) steps are listed in order to try as (do not do next step until the prior has passed).

1. Ping `host.domain.tld`, get an ICMP response.
2. Execute `delv host.domain.tld.` and ensure that the first output line shows `; fully validated`; please note the period (`.`) added at end of your hostname.
3. Exercise proper `EDNS(0)` using this [EDNS(0) online tester](https://ednscomp.isc.org/ednscomp) against your server in question.
4. Get the SSH fingerprint from your SSH server in question to start the comparison; execute `ssh-keyscan -D host.domain.tld.`  (note the `-D` option).

```shell
$ ssh-keyscan -D host.domain.tld.
```

which outputs:

```
host.domain.tld IN SSHFP 4 1 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
host.domain.tld IN SSHFP 4 2 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

5. From a DNS query of the authoritative nameserver that is holding the SSHFP in its zone database file, obtain the `SSHFP` record using `delv host.domain.tld. SSHFP`.

```bash
$ delv host.domain.tld. sshfp
```

generates the following output:

```
; fully validated
host.domain.tld.        86400   IN  SSHFP   1 1 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
host.domain.tld.        86400   IN  SSHFP   1 2 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX
host.domain.tld.        86400   IN  SSHFP   3 1 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
host.domain.tld.        86400   IN  SSHFP   3 2 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX
host.domain.tld.        86400   IN  SSHFP   4 1 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
host.domain.tld.        86400   IN  SSHFP   4 2 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX
```

6. Compare actual SSH fingerprint with the what the `SSHFP` DNS record says. The algorithm (1-6) and hash ID (1 or 2) must both match as well.

The algorithm ID to name that must match are: 1=RSA, 2=DSA, 3=ECDSA, 4=Ed25519, 6=Ed448.

The hash ID to name that must match are:  1=SHA1, 2=SHA256.

7. Try `ssh -oVerifyHostKeyDNS=yes -oStrictHostKeyChecking=yes host.domain.tld.`   If this step works, integrate both options into your SSH client config file.

If the fingerprints do not match, it is always invariably the DNS record that needs updating.

## WARNING Appeared

With newer OpenSSH, you might even get the following pesky prompt during an initial SSH login:

```
ssh host.domain.tld
```

may outputs the following:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ED25519 key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:XxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXx.
Please contact your system administrator.
Update the SSHFP RR in DNS with the new host key to get rid of this message.
Warning: Permanently added '[host.domain.tld.]:22,[999.999.999.999]:22' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
</etc/motd content goes here>
user@host.domain.tld.'s password:
```

The key thing to note in the above output is the following line:

```
Update the SSHFP RR in DNS with the new host key to get rid of this message.
```

It means exactly what it means.

The `VerifyHostKeyDNS yes` in your local SSH client config is what
controls that output; the config being either in `$USER/.ssh/config` or in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`.

The above decision is based on a simple comparison between:

- authoritative nameserver holding the `SSHFP` zone data of this `host.domain.tld`
- The SSH server of `host.domain.tld` providing the public key

This message covers 99.999% of the following potential scenario.

- `sshd` is not using the same pubkey, possibly due to:

  - a different pubkey has been generated via `ssh-keygen` (most common)
  - a different set of config file (via `sshd -c <config_file>`)
  - `AuthorizedKeyFile` had been change
  - fingerprint hash (`FingerprintHash`) setting had been changed
  - `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes` had been changed
  - `CASignatureAlgorithms` had been changed
  - `TrustedCAUserKeys` had been changed

The other 0.001% of the time is broken down in one of the many not so common scenarios:

- points to a different SSH server

  - a new port number has been opened (legitmately or not). This can happen if your `ssh_config`/`$HOME/.ssh/config` has used a different port number (rare but has maliciously happened)
  - a (different?) Dockerized container reusing same IP address
  - MAC address has been changed to point to a cloned server
  - IP filter (or nftables) rerouted your usual SSH port
  - IP route has been changed (by route table or by various IP route protocol like BGP, OSPF, RIP)
  - a ghost daemon appeared such that your server's rouge `sshd` daemon got its start through SysV init (`service XXXX start` or `systemd start XXXX.service` or `system start XXXX.timer` or furtively via crond/atd job or even `rc.local`) and is using its own SSH server public key.
- points to a different `sshd` executable. This requires file validation by package tools (of your distro in ascertaining that it’s checksum value, modification time, file path, security context, and attributes of not only the `sshd` executable file but its referenced libraries (see `ldd/usr/sbin/sshd`) are all computed and set correctly.

At any rate, once you've eliminated the remaining 0.001%, it is a simple matter of:

- Generate new `SSHFP` DNS record (`ssh-keyscan -r host.domain.tld`); save the output to an editor buffer
- Identifying the authoritative nameserver of `domain.tld` (`dig domain.tld. soa` and note the `MNAME` portion of SOA record data).
- Log in as root on that `MNAME` authoritative nameserver of `host.domain.tld`
- go to the correct config file of nameserver (ISC Bind9 is `/etc/named.conf`; newer Bind v9.11+ shows default config via `named -V`)
- Note the database file name of the `domain.tld` zone. (ISC Bind9 is `file /var/lib/bind/db.domain.tld`)
- change the directory to where that zone database file is located at
- Edit the `db.domain.tld` file.
- paste the new `SSHFP` DNS records from the editor buffer that you saved in the first step.

Might want to put that period (`.`) symbol directly at the end of the host name for each of these `SSHFP` data records (that was generated by `ssh-keyscan` before closing that zone database file; such that:

```
; note the extra ending period '.' after hostnames
host.domain.tld. IN SSHFP 4 1 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
host.domain.tld. IN SSHFP 4 2 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Enjoy!

Source:

- https://fanf.livejournal.com/130577.html
- https://egbert.net/blog/articles/dns-rr-sshfp.html

Comment: Ok, clarified by prefacing details on `insecure fingerprints` and expanding on what newer OpenSSH versions would do (since v6.9, now at v9.0).  Thanks, @anx